# 'click' event firing multiple times, no solutions working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been asked several times, but none of the solutions seem to be working for me.  I've got an issue where the click event that I am adding to some elements upon loading the document fires multiple times.  What's really weird is that the amount of times it fires increases with every click, as if the event is being re-bound with each click.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  BindUserControls('#log_in', '/users/sign_in')
  BindUserControls('#sign_up', '/users/sign_up')
})

var BindUserControls = function(button, path) {
  $(button).click( function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: path
    })
    .done(function(data){
      $('.modal-content').empty()
      $('.modal-content').prepend(data)
      $('.modal').modal('show')
    })
  })
}
```

The solutions I've tried so far include

- adding .off() prior to .on()
- unbinding the event within the same function
- delegating the event through the body of the document

Nothing seems to be working.  I've also disabled turbo-links, I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you written your above code in `sign_up` and `sign_in` files?

Comment: Did you try stopping propagation of the event?

Comment: Please provide us your PHP code. I never have that before. Try only to use `sleep(1);` before you load other scripts in PHP to prevent multiple calls

Comment: @Satpal this code is written in a file called user_controls.js inside of a Rails app.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal I just tried stopping the propagation of the event right before the ajax call, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  BindUserControls('#log_in', '/users/sign_in')
  BindUserControls('#sign_up', '/users/sign_up')
})

var BindUserControls = function(button, path) {
  $(button).click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: path
    })
    .done(function(data){
      $('.modal-content').empty()
      $('.modal-content').prepend(data)
      $('.modal').modal('show')
    });
    return false;
  });
};
```

And try to put `sleep(1);` on first line in your AJAX PHP file to prevent multiple calls.

Another solution may be:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
      BindUserControls('#log_in', '/users/sign_in')
      BindUserControls('#sign_up', '/users/sign_up')
    })

    var BindUserControls = function(button, path) {
      $(button).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        clearInterval(interval);
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: path
                })
                .done(function(data){
                  $('.modal-content').empty()
                  $('.modal-content').prepend(data)
                  $('.modal').modal('show')
                });
                clearInterval(interval);
        }, 300);
        return false;
      });
    };
```

But I not test this. I use similar function for somthing else and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a solution.  Basically, I added a class to each of the elements that the click event is on, then called '.off()' on that class, within the BindUserControls function.  I had tried using '.off()' earlier, but in a different manner - I had done something along the lines of '$(button).off(...).on(...)', which didn't work for me.  Thanks for all the answers!  Below is my code:

```
var BindUserControls = function(button, path) {
  $(button).on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: path
    })
    .done(function(data){
      $('.modal-content').empty()
      $('.modal-content').prepend(data)
      $('.modal').modal('show')
    })
    $('.user_controls').off()
  })
}
```

Comment: `.off()` unbinds all handlers, you should use `.off("click")` instead